Can you derive the program owner of a SPL token?
Is there any way to derive the program owner of a token locally without having to use the GetAccountInfo call for example. Such that if I input a token address, it will return whether it is apart of the new or old token programs?
For example that a token such as 7atgF8KQo4wJrD5ATGX7t1V2zVvykPJbFfNeVf1icFv1 will show thats its owner is TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb.

This is not possible.
You need to request to determine whether an account is actually on the Solana state.
For example, with an ATA it's possible to derive the address using the wallet and token mint, but that doesn't mean that the account will exist and be owned by the token program.
